# Retrieve firebase server time without setting it first

Tags: php, firebase

Is there a way to obtain the server time without having to first set it? For example, I can simply do:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{".sv": "timestamp"}' https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/servertime.json
```

which will return the server time, but this sets the value `servertime` within my firebase instance. I should note that I'm using the REST API.

Comment: Firebase is all about client-to-client communication. I don't think it currently exposes its server-side time.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It does, for entries put into firebase you can use the JSON above or use `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` (see: https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-presence.html) - which I can do fine but I dont want to actually write the server time, I just want to get it. The solution above works fine, I just want to be able to do it without having to write/delete the value.

Comment: I was facing the same problem and It looks you just need dummy timestamp field where you put placeholder and than listen to it when the server changes it to the real timestamp. If you have multiple users or apps asking it it has to be dummy field for each one of them as they can compete for one.

Answer (score 7):

You can retrieve the server time without writing it by using [.info/serverTimeOffset](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-presence.html):

```
var fbRef = new Firebase(URL);

var getServerTime = (function(ref) {
    var offset = 0;
    ref.child('.info/serverTimeOffset').on('value', function(snap) {
       offset = snap.val();
    });

    return function() {
       return Date.now() + offset;
    }
})(fbRef);

var now = getServerTime();
```

Comment: What would this value be when using the REST API? I'd assume https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/.info/serverTimeOffset.json but that gives `invalid path`

Comment: Not available via the REST API, afaik.

Comment: That's what I figured (I'm using a service to clear out old entries automatically after 15 minutes based on the firebase server time).

Comment: it return -123 value

Comment: @Kato offset is always negative no matter whether my clock is ahead of firebase or behind so how to decide whether to add or subtract offset from the client's clock?

Comment: @Kato Sorry. It was my mistake. I was changing time and expecting firebase to immediately change offset. Indeed firebase gives positive or negative based on whether ahead or lagging